# How do I add a Dynamic Link in Custom HTML Widget?

Tags: html, wordpress, url, path, widget

I am developing a website on my local environment and want to add "Custom HTML" widgets to my website footer and megamenu. I want to be able to add images and links through these custom HTML widgets.

The problem is that I have to hardcode the absolute URL path (e.g. http://localhost/client_projects/hom/site/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/image.png)

When the time arrives to go live I will have to root out and swap all the URLs in my widgets. Not good.

So how do I dynamically link to pages and images in *Custom HTML widgets*?

Comment: You can use this plugin "https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/".

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic tokens/variables using add_filter.

Add the following to functions.php:

```
add_filter('widget_text', function($text) {
    $upload_dir_array = wp_upload_dir();           
    $text = str_replace('{{uploads_dir}}', $upload_dir_array['baseurl'], $text);

    return $text;
});
```

Now in your Custom HTML widget, write your URLs as `{{uploads_dir}/2018/03/image.png`.